# add numpy array to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Im experimenting with time series predictions something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

model = SARIMAX(data.values, 
                order=order, 
                seasonal_order=seasonal_order)

result = model.fit()

train = data.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0)
test = data.drop(train.index)
start = len(train)
end = len(train) + len(test) - 1
  
# Predictions for one-year against the test set
predictions = result.predict(start, end,
                             typ='levels')
```

where predictions is a numpy array. How do I add this to my `test` pandas df? If I try this:
`test['predicted'] = predictions.tolist()`

This wont contact properly where I was hoping to add in the prediction as another column in my df. It looks like this below:

```
hour
2021-06-07 17:00:00                                          75726.57143
2021-06-07 20:00:00                                          62670.06667
2021-06-08 00:00:00                                             16521.65
2021-06-08 14:00:00                                              71628.1
2021-06-08 17:00:00                                          62437.16667
                                             ...                        
2021-09-23 22:00:00                                          7108.533333
2021-09-24 02:00:00                                              13325.2
2021-09-24 04:00:00                                          13322.31667
2021-09-24 13:00:00                                             37941.65
predicted              [13605.31231433516, 12597.907337725523, 13484....  <--- not coming in as another df column
```

Would anyone have any advice? Am hoping to ultimately plot the predicted values against the test values as well as calculate rsme maybe something like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from statsmodels.tools.eval_measures import rmse

# Calculate root mean squared error
rmse(test, predictions)
  
# Calculate mean squared error
mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
```

***EDIT***

```
train = data.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0)
test = data.drop(train.index)

start = len(train)
end = len(train) + len(test) - 1
```

Comment: What is `predictions` data type? Does its length match the number of rows in `test`? Is `test` a DataFrame or a Series?

Comment: `predictions` is  `numpy.ndarray`. `len(numpy.ndarray` is `520` and `len(test)` is `521`...ill have to figure this one out why they are not both the same

Comment: I added in an EDIT for how I am trying to calculate `start` and `end` where this must be where I am doing something wrong

Comment: Should it not be ˋtest['predictions'] = predictions.tolist()ˋ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add it as a column directly without needing to do any additional conversion. The output from `result.predict()` should be a Pandas series. If not, you should still be able to simply add it directly to the dataframe so long as it's the same length and order.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020', '01-04-2020', '01-05-2020'],
                     'value': [15, 25, 35, 45 ,55]}
                   )
test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['date'])
test = test.set_index('date')

predictions = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])

test['predictions'] = predictions
```

Output:

```
            value  predictions
date                          
2020-01-01     15           10
2020-01-02     25           20
2020-01-03     35           30
2020-01-04     45           40
2020-01-05     55           50
```